# How to remove a row from Pandas dataframe based on row value

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a program to discretize a set of attributes via entropy discretization. The goal is to parse the dataset

```
A,Class
5,1
12.5,1
11.5,2
8.6,2
7,1
6,1
5.9,2
1.5,2
9,2
7.8,1
2.1,1
13.5,2
12.45,2
```

Into

```
A,Class
1,1
3,1
3,2
2,2
2,1
2,1
1,2
1,2
3,2
2,1
1,1
3,2
3,2
```

The specific problem that I am facing is that I would like to use a pandas method to remove the row associated with the calculated threshold. My attempt at doing this was `s['A'].drop[s.iloc[0]]`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import entropy_based_binning as ebb
from math import log2
from random import randrange, uniform

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('S1.csv')
    s = df
    s = entropy_discretization(s)

# This method discretizes s A1
# If the information gain is 0, i.e the number of 
# distinct class is 1 or
# If min f/ max f < 0.5 and the number of distinct values is floor(n/2)
# Then that partition stops splitting.
def entropy_discretization(s):

    I = {}
    while(uniqueValue(s)):
        # Step 1: pick a threshold
        threshold = s['A'].iloc[0]

        # Step 2: Partititon the data set into two parttitions
        s1 = s[s['A'] < threshold]
        print("s1 after spitting")
        print(s1)
        print("******************")
        s2 = s[s['A'] >= threshold]
        print("s2 after spitting")
        print(s2)
        print("******************")
            
        # Step 3: calculate the information gain.
        informationGain = information_gain(s1,s2,s)
        print(f'Calculated information gain {informationGain}')

        I.update({'informationGain':informationGain,'threshold':threshold})
        print(I)
        s['A'].drop[s.iloc[0]]

    # Step 5: calculate the max information gain
    maxInformationGain = np.amax(informationGain)
    print(f'Calculated maximum information gain {maxInformationGain}')


    # Step 6: keep the partitions of S based on the value of threshold_i
    s = bestPartition(minInformationGain, s)

def uniqueValue(s):
    # are records in s the same? return true
    if s.nunique()['A'] == 1:
        return False
    # otherwise false 
    else:
        return True

def bestPartition(maxInformationGain):
    # determine be threshold_i
    threshold_i = 6

    return 


def information_gain(s1, s2, s):
    # calculate cardinality for s1
    cardinalityS1 = len(pd.Index(s1['A']).value_counts())
    print(f'The Cardinality of s1 is: {cardinalityS1}')
    # calculate cardinality for s2
    cardinalityS2 = len(pd.Index(s2['A']).value_counts())
    print(f'The Cardinality of s2 is: {cardinalityS2}')
    # calculate cardinality of s
    cardinalityS = len(pd.Index(s['A']).value_counts())
    print(f'The Cardinality of s is: {cardinalityS}')
    # calculate informationGain
    informationGain = (cardinalityS1/cardinalityS) * entropy(s1) + (cardinalityS2/cardinalityS) * entropy(s2)
    print(f'The total informationGain is: {informationGain}')
    return informationGain



def entropy(s):
    print("calculating the entropy for s")
    print("*****************************")
    print(s)
    print("*****************************")

    # initialize ent
    ent = 0

    # calculate the number of classes in s
    numberOfClasses = s['Class'].nunique()
    print(f'Number of classes for dataset: {numberOfClasses}')
    value_counts = s['Class'].value_counts()
    p = []
    for i in range(0,numberOfClasses):
        n = s['Class'].count()
        # calculate the frequency of class_i in S1
        print(f'p{i} {value_counts.iloc[i]}/{n}')
        f = value_counts.iloc[i]
        pi = f/n
        p.append(pi)
    
    print(p)

    for pi in p:
        ent += -pi*log2(pi)

    return ent 

main()
```

Ideally, I'd like to remove the row that has the same value as the variable `threshold`.

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** and **reproducible** example

Comment: I've provided the dataset and the python code.

Comment: But it's neither minimal, nor (easily) reproducible

Comment: The variable `threshold` is equal to the row? It should be more specific like a particular value for the row, as a pandas row is a series.

Comment: command c the python code, command v into vs code. command c the dataset, command v int file S1.csv. run python my_prog.py

Comment: You're providing to much information. Yes, you provided a sample dataframe, but you make ppl to read your code and figure out what the relation between `threshold` and your data, which is not obvious. Then, you ask to remove data *has the samve value as the variable `threshold`*, which is even less obvious as there is no `value` in your data.

Comment: @avats I'd like to remove the row that is equal to the threshold.

Comment: `s = s[s['A'] != threshold]` is right. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
S = S[S['A']!=threshold]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to remove the row that was equivalent to the threshold value. The point of this algorithm is to remove the unique values from the dataset. This can be achieved with

```
s = s[s['A'] != threshold]
```

It is used like so

```
def entropy_discretization(s):

    I = {}
    while(uniqueValue(s)):
        # Step 1: pick a threshold
        threshold = s['A'].iloc[0]

        # Step 2: Partititon the data set into two parttitions
        s1 = s[s['A'] < threshold]
        print("s1 after spitting")
        print(s1)
        print("******************")
        s2 = s[s['A'] >= threshold]
        print("s2 after spitting")
        print(s2)
        print("******************")
            
        # Step 3: calculate the information gain.
        informationGain = information_gain(s1,s2,s)
        print(f'Calculated information gain {informationGain}')

        I.update({'informationGain':informationGain,'threshold':threshold})
        s = s[s['A'] != threshold]
        print(I)

    print(I)
    # Step 5: calculate the max information gain
    # maxInformationGain = np.amax(informationGain)
    # print(f'Calculated maximum information gain {maxInformationGain}')


    # Step 6: keep the partitions of S based on the value of threshold_i
    # s = bestPartition(maxInformationGain, s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to drop the row equal to threshold rather than keep rows that are not equal to threshold, use `drop`:

```
s.drop(s[s['A'] == threshold)].index, inplace=True)
```